What is this note-taking convention?
I have come across similar auctions a few times but have not been able to figure out what the convention is. Will be thankful if someone can help.
N. E. S. W
P. P. 1D  P
1H p. 1S. P
2c p

2c is Alert asking partner to bid 2d and may hide a weak hand with diamonds or an invitational hand.
Thanks

This is the XYZ convention. It applies when the partnership has made their first three bids at the 1 level. Briefly, 2D is an artificial game force and 2C is a relay to 2D, either to sign off or to describe an invitational hand. It's an extension of two-way New Minor Forcing to any rebid at the one level by opener, instead of just 1NT.

Ok. Thank you so much. That is very helpful and so kind of you to answering

Can it not just be fourth suit forcing?

Fourth-suit forcing doesn't relay partner into 2D and is not bid when you have a hand that wants to sign off in diamonds. I agree that many partnerships play fourth-suit forcing here, but that doesn't match the description given in this case.

2C is not a "relays". 2C is a puppet.  A relay is an artificial bid asking partner to describe their hand. A puppet is an artificial bid forcing partner to make an automatic bid which says nothing about their hand. Puppets and relays are two very different concepts.

@Michal I don't know how to tell you this, but this usage is common. But go off with your prescriptivist self

But also, from the link in the post: "Although it is mandatory in the XY Notrump form of the convention to complete the relay 2♣ to 2♦, when Z was a suit, opener may be unlimited. In such a case it is acceptable, if opener has too good a hand to risk being dropped in 2♦ to bypass the relay and make a (forcing) bid."

@ruds - common it might be, it is not correct.  After all, last time I checked Puppet Stayman was called Puppet Stayman not "Relay" Stayman.

Words mean what they are used to mean, not what one person thinks they should mean. A puppet bid and a "relay to" are essentially the same thing in common usage.
